# ReactJS: jquery library issue

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am creating a form in reactjs to submit the data into the database via laravel api. I need the form fields to be validated before send the request to the api to save the data.

I have installed the jquery library(v3.3.1) and imported it into my component `import $ from 'jquery';`, but when I am adding any jquery code/functionality in `componentDidMount()`, which is called after the render method is executed, its not working.

**Here is my code:**

```
componentDidMount()
{
    $(".js-status").on("click", function () {
        alert("Button clicked");
    });
}

render() 
{
    return (
        <button className="js-status" onClick={
            () => this.setStatus(project.token, 'N')
        }>Inactive</button>
    );
}
```

However, if I write the code in `$(window).on("load", function() {});` then it starts working.

**Like this:**

```
componentDidMount()
{
    $(window).on("load", function() {
        $(".js-status").on("click", function () {
            alert("Button clicked");
        });
    });
}
```

Now my questions is that, **why isn't it working without the "window.load" event..?**

I am following this youtube tutorial https://youtu.be/AMMetkCvztg

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but: unless you have an extremely good reason, I wouldn't recommend using jQuery with React. jQuery relies very heavily on imperative APIs and direct manipulation of the DOM, which doesn't mesh well with React's more functional API/usage of virtual DOM.

Comment: Form validation is [possible with React alone](https://learnetto.com/blog/how-to-do-simple-form-validation-in-reactjs), and there's [various libraries](https://github.com/lonelyplanet/react-validate-form) if you need something with more 'out of the box' functionality.

Comment: Thanks @JoeClay, I'll keep that in mind.